# XML parsing in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I would like to parse the XML data that is coming through this feed:
http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote/

in the format

```
Name Price Symbol Volume
```

Please could someone provide the code? I am not good at working with PHP.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes , I googled it for xml parsing but was unable to convet it as per the need . The values are coming blank hence I am sure I have missed something ..

Comment: @Abhishek https://www.google.com/search?q=php+xml+xml-parsing worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it out and got it working with the following code:

```
$xmlUrl = "http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote/";
$xmlStr = file_get_contents($xmlUrl);
$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xmlStr);
$resArr = $xmlObj->resources->resource;
$count = $resArr->count();

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $name   = (string) $resArr[$i]->field[0];
    $price  = (string) $resArr[$i]->field[1];
    $symbol = (string) $resArr[$i]->field[2];
    $volume = (string) $resArr[$i]->field[6];
    print_r("name: {$name}, price: {$price}, symbol: {$symbol}, volume: {$volume}<br />");
}
```

I'm not to fond about getting the fields by index, but found that the name attributes in the fields were not taken into account by `simplexml`.

Comment: Thanks kalle :)
I also tries it and its working 
Do you think this would be the best method I can use